# Convert a list of lists into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a list of lists into a nested dictionary:

My code:

```
csv_data={}
    for key, value in csv_files.iteritems():
        if key in desired_keys:
            csv_data[key]=[]

            for element in value:
                csv_data[key].append(element[1:])
```

This code gives me the following:

```
{   'Network': [
        ['Total KB/sec', 'Sent KB/sec', 'Received KB/sec'],
        ['0.3', '0.1', '0.3']
    ],
    'CPU': [
        ['Processor Time', 'User Time', 'Privileged Time'],
        ['13.8', '6.7', '7.2']
    ]
}
```

So in this case each "value" is a list containing two lists, containung a "title" list and a "numerical value" list

However I want to produce a format like:

```
{   'Network': {
        'Total KB/sec':0.3,
        'Sent KB/sec':0.1,
        'Received KB/sec':0.3
    },
    'CPU': {
        'Processor Time':'13.8',
        'User Time': '6.7',
        'Privileged Time': '7.2'
    }
}
```

How should I change my code to produce this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I demonstrate the use of `zip()` on one of your keys, `Network`:

```
>>> network = [
    ['Total KB/sec', 'Sent KB/sec', 'Received KB/sec'],
    ['0.3', '0.1', '0.3']
]
```

`zip()`ing the two lists will yield a set of tuples that can be turned into a dict, by simply calling `dict()` on it. In other words,

```
>>> dict(zip(network[0], network[1]))
{'Received KB/sec': '0.3', 'Sent KB/sec': '0.1', 'Total KB/sec': '0.3'}
```

Repeat for your `CPU` key.

Comment: I'll just leave the one-liner I wrote here, may it be useful to OP and not go to waste. `csv_data[key]= dict(zip(*(row[1:] for row in value)))`

Answer (score 2):

`zip()` comes in very handy for iterating the lists at the same time, and converting to a dictionary becomes very easy with `dict()`.

```
def to_dict(dic):
    for key, value in dic.iteritems():
        dic[key] = dict(zip(* value))
    return dic
```

**Sample output:**

```
d = {'Network': [['Total KB/sec', 'Sent KB/sec', 'Received KB/sec'],
['0.3', '0.1', '0.3']],
'CPU': [['Processor Time', 'User Time', 'Privileged Time'],
['13.8', 6.7', '7.2']]}

print to_dict(d)
>>> {'Network': {'Sent KB/sec': '0.1', 'Total KB/sec': '0.3', 'Received 
KB/sec': '0.3'}, 'CPU': {'Processor Time': '13.8', 'Privileged Time': 
'7.2', 'User Time': '6.7'}}
```

**How does it work?**

When you use the zip function on lists it returns a list of **tuple pairs** and iterates the various levels of lists treating them as *parallel lists* by coupling each of the lists elements spanning the lists at their *respective* index. So if we isolate the `zip(* value)` operation we can clearly see the result of the operation:

```
>>> [('Total KB/sec', '0.3'), ('Sent KB/sec', '0.1'), ('Received 
    KB/sec', '0.3')]
    [('Processor Time', '13.8'), ('User Time', '6.7'), ('Privileged 
    Time', '7.2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach without `zip`

```
dct = {   'Network': [
        ['Total KB/sec', 'Sent KB/sec', 'Received KB/sec'],
        ['0.3', '0.1', '0.3']
    ],
    'CPU': [
        ['Processor Time', 'User Time', 'Privileged Time'],
        ['13.8', '6.7', '7.2']
    ]
}

for key, val in dct.items():
    placeholder_dct= {}
    for i in range(len(val[0])):
        placeholder_dct[val[0][i]] = val[1][i]
    dct[key] = placeholder_dct

print(dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
{x:{z:t for z,t in (dict(zip(y[0], y[1]))).items()} for x,y in data.items()}
```

When Input :

```
data={   'Network': [
    ['Total KB/sec', 'Sent KB/sec', 'Received KB/sec'],
    ['0.3', '0.1', '0.3']
],
'CPU': [
    ['Processor Time', 'User Time', 'Privileged Time'],
    ['13.8', '6.7', '7.2']
]}
```

Output :

```
res= {'Network': {'Sent KB/sec': '0.1', 'Total KB/sec': '0.3', 'Received KB/sec': '0.3'}, 'CPU': {'Processor Time': '13.8', 'Privileged Time': '7.2', 'User Time': '6.7'}}
```