# How do I convert from a list of tuples and integers to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list containing tuples and integers 
e.g.

```
mylist = [ (('ART', 'bar'), 2), (('ART', 'get'), 1), (('b', 'bet'), 1), (('b', 'chest'), 1), (('b', 'kart'), 2), (('b', 'zee'), 1)]
```

which I want to convert to this nested dictionary

```
my_dict = {
    "ART": {"bar": 2, "get": 1},
    "b": {"bet": 1, "chest": 1, "kart": 2,"zee": 1}
}
```

I've been trying to do this using for loops but I'm a beginner and I don't have any experience with nested dictionaries so I really don't know where to start.
I've looked at other questions related to dictionaries of dictionaries e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186918/converting-list-of-lists-into-a-dictionary-of-dictionaries-in-python/52187017) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592504/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-nested-dictionary) but the methods suggested aren't working for me (I assume because I am dealing with tuples rather than just lists of lists.)

Comment: Please add your code, what have you attempted? In that way contributors can find and explain what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 5):

You could loop over the input and use `setdefault` to populate the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
for (key, prop), value in mylist:
    my_dict.setdefault(key, {})[prop] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mylist = [ (('ART', 'bar'), 2), (('ART', 'get'), 1), (('b', 'bet'), 1), 

(('b', 'chest'), 1), (('b', 'kart'), 2), (('b', 'zee'), 1)]
mydict = dict()

for i in mylist:
    if i[0][0] not in mydict.keys():
        mydict[i[0][0]] = {i[0][1]: i[1]}
    else:
        mydict[i[0][0]][i[0][1]] = i[1]
print(mydict)
```